# Video stream delayed on wowza server and quality is very low from ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, wowza

Form ffmpeg i fired some command to  run video  on wowza server

```
ffmpeg -i /home/Downloads/GAmUk.mp4  -f mpegts udp:/ip:10000/live/test.stream
```

and streaming is running as well only problem is latency not so good its played after long time on server please help me to play fast

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide more info as to how you are playing it back.  What player, protocl, etc.

I'll make some guesses.

RTMP has very low latency, so I'm guessing you are not playing back using this protocol.

HTTP streaming methods such as Apple HLS, Adobe HDS, and Smooth streaming have a longer latency by their nature.  Usually the latency is 3 chunks of video.  Wowza allows you to configure the duration of each chunk (keyframe duration also comes into play).  So if your chunks are 10 seconds, you'll have at least 30 seconds of latency.

I would consult wowza's forums.  We have a very active support staff and developer community who can help you dig deeper.

Scott

Comment: thank u very much actully   ya its wowza rtmp only and command which have exactly    ./ffmpeg -i "http://www.wowza.com/_h264/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" -vcodec libx264 -vb 150000 -g 60 -vprofile baseline -level 2.1  -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://ip:10000   can we make rtmp protocol with higher latency or better to move http ..

Comment: and video coming that is also very blurry